# CSS - Vertical dorp-down menu doesn't work on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a two-layer and vertical drop-down menu.
Each main menu has 20 items (submenu) separately.
It is normal when being looked over with chrome's toggle device toolbar.
However, it doesn't work on mobile device, the items beyond one page are invisible.
Is there any way to resolve this problem?  Many thanks.

```js
 $(function(){
     $('.btn-primary ').click(function(){
            $('ul').hide('fast');     
            $('ul',this).show('fast');
     });
 });
```

```css
    li{list-style: none;}
    .btn-primary{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        color:white;
        font-size:22px;
        width:150px;
        background-color: #353535;
        position: relative;
    }
    .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active{
        border-style:none;
        background-color: #233858;
     }
    .submenu{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position:absolute;   
        top:0;
        left:80%;
        width:150px;
        display: none;    
    }
    .btn{
        margin-bottom:10px;
        height:36px;
        background-color:#233858;   
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="container">
        <button class='btn-primary'>menu 1
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 1-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>
        <button class='btn-primary'>menu 2
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 2-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>
        <button class='btn-primary'>menu 3
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 3-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>                 
    </div>
```

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52bjB.png)

Comment: I couldn't understand can you describe it more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a css to `ul` by setting the `max-height` and `overflow` to `auto` with never ever goes beyond the `max-width` , if there are more elements exist, it will add the scroll bar automatically. So you don't need to worry about scroll.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn-primary ').click(function() {
    $('ul').hide('fast');
    $('ul', this).show('fast');
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.btn-primary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #353535;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #233858;
}

.submenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 80%;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #233858;
}
ul{
  max-height:250px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class='btn-primary'>menu 1
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 1-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>
  <button class='btn-primary'>menu 2
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 2-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>
  <button class='btn-primary'>menu 3
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 3-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help. If you found this answer is helpfull please upvote and mark as correct

Answer (score 1):

*Try this code. this works in mobile, also I added toggle hide and show in it.*

```js
 $(function(){
     $('.btn-primary ').click(function(){
            $('ul').hide('fast');
            var x = $('ul',this).css('display');
            if (x === "none") {
                $('ul',this).show('fast');
            } else {
                $('ul',this).hide('fast');
            }
     });
 });
```

```css
    li{list-style: none;}
    .btn-primary{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        color:white;
        font-size:22px;
        width:150px;
        background-color: #353535;
        position: relative;
    }
    .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active{
        border-style:none;
        background-color: #233858;
     }
    .submenu{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position:absolute;   
        top:0;
        left:80%;
        width:150px;
        display: none;    
    }
    .btn{
        margin-bottom:10px;
        height:36px;
        background-color:#233858;   
    }
    @media(max-width: 767px){
      .submenu{
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          position:absolute;   
          top:35px;
          left:0;
          padding:0;
          width:150px;
          display: none; 
          z-index:1;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="container">
        <button class='btn-primary'>menu 1
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 1-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 1-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>
        <button class='btn-primary'>menu 2
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 2-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 2-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>
        <button class='btn-primary'>menu 3
            <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="btn">menu 3-01</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-02</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-03</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-04</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-05</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-06</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-07</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-08</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-09</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-10</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-11</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-12</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-13</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-14</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-15</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-16</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-17</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-18</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-19</li>
       <li class="btn">menu 3-20</li>
            </ul>
        </button>                 
    </div>
```